# boost::asio fails to catch SIGINT

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, ros

My following program never reaches to handler(). I am installing my own signal handler using signal set.

```
void handler( const boost::system::error_code& error , int signal_number )
{
  ROS_ERROR("inside signal handler");
  exit(1);
}
 int main( int argc , char** argv )
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "name", ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;


// Construct a signal set registered for process termination.
  boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_service, SIGINT );
       // Start an asynchronous wait for one of the signals to occur.
  signals.async_wait( handler );

 boost::asio::spawn(io_service, {
    while(1);
 }
);



io_service.run();
  return 0;
}
```

interesting, when i use

```
  signals.async_wait(
      [&ioSservice](boost::system::error_code& code, int signalNo) {
        ioService.stop();
      });
```

then it does not terminate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have one thread servicing your `io_service`, and it's busy with the `while(1);` so it can't run the signal handler.

An `io_service` acts like a queue.  When you `async_wait` on things, asio will arrange for the callbacks to be added queued to run through their associated `io_service`.  When you call `io_service::run`, the calling thread will pull pending items from the `io_service`'s queue and run them.

In this case, when you call `io_service.run()`, there's on job in the queue: the one created by `spawn` that runs an endless `while` loop.  Since the loop never ends, the main thread can never finish running that job.  Later, when `signal_set` receives the `SIGINT`, it adds another job to the queue to call `handler`, but it will never be run because the only thread pulling jobs out of the queue is busy with an endless `while` loop.

The way to handle this is to avoid putting long-running jobs in your `io_service`'s queue and/or to have multiple threads servicing the `io_service`:

```
void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, int signal_number)
{
  std::cout << "inside signal handler\n";
  exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // You can use a work object to avoid having the io_service
  // stop when its job queue empties.
  boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);

  boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_service, SIGINT);
  signals.async_wait(handler);

  // Now that there's a work object keeping this io_service running
  // this call isn't needed at all.  It's just here to demonstrate
  // that it works
  boost::asio::spawn(io_service, []{
      while(1);
    }
  );

  // Start a second thread to run io_service jobs
  std::thread t([&io_service]{ io_service.run(); });

  // Also handle io_service jobs on this thread
  io_service.run();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: it receives signal  handler but still escalating to `SIGTERM`. May be something needs to modify with ros code.

Comment: I didn't add any of the ROS stuff in my example since I have no experience with that.  You'll probably need to add back the `ros::init` call.

Comment: I have ros::init call in my code if you see my question.

Comment: Right, my point was that it isn't in my example snippet.  If you copied that and compiled it then ROS may be interfering with boost's signal handling.  If you have the `ros::init` call then it's hard for me to say what's wrong.  Like I said, I have no experience with ROS.

Comment: Anolther way is to use `work`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5070e93a58784b71 (hard to demo online, it does correctly report _`"./sotest 
^Cinside signal handler: Success signal 2"`_ for me locally)

Comment: @MilesBudnek can you please check updated question. why it does not terminate when we dont use `exit()`

Comment: @debonair Why would it?  `io_service::stop` just stops dispatching jobs.  It doesn't interrupt any running jobs.  Once a thread starts running the infinite loop the only way out is to terminate the process.

Comment: if `asio::spawn` is put on sleep in `while` does it schedule another item?

Comment: @debonair Likely yes, the `io_service` worker is free to do other things while the `spawn`ed function is asynchronously waiting for something.  I don't know that totally for sure though; I've never used `spawn` specifically.